# Trying to simplify LINQ expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to simplify a LINQ expression but no matter what i try I'm unable to get it to work

```
var filterProfileIds = filter.Profiles.Select(s => s.ProfileId);
var newList = new List<FileMedia>();
foreach (var item in filterProfileIds)
{
     newList.AddRange(query.Where(w => w.Profiles.Select(s => s.ProfileId).Contains(item)));

}

newList.AddRange(query.Where(w => !w.Profiles.Any()));

query = newList.AsQueryable();
```

query is of type "FileMedia" and has a relation to Profiles.

So what i want is all the results from the query that has the same profiles that filter.profiles has AND i also want all the results from the query that doesnt have any profiles at all.

Comment: Seems like an [left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin) to me

Comment: Show `query` please.

Comment: @NEER question is updated with the query

Comment: @grimsan55 How do you fill `query` Show it please.

Comment: query = _dbContext.Media.OfType<FileMedia>().Include(i => i.File).Include(i => i.Profiles);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as the below:

```
var filterProfileIds = filter.Profiles.Select(s => s.ProfileId);
query = query.Where(w => 
                    !w.Profiles.Any() || 
                     w.Profiles.Any(i => filterProfileIds.Contains(i.ProfileId))
                ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the requirement, you could use a combination of `Any` and `All` extension methods like this:

```
query = query.Where(m => !m.Profiles.Any() || 
    filterProfileIds.All(id => m.Profiles.Any(p => p.ProfiledId == id)));
```

This is if you wish to get the items with exact the same profiles as the filter.

If you indeed want to get the item with any profile contained in the filter, then you could use this instead:

```
query = query.Where(m => !m.Profiles.Any() ||
    m.Profiles.Any(p => filterProfileIds.Contains(p.ProfiledId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
query = (from item in filter.Profiles.Select(s => s.ProfileId)
         from fileMedia in query
         where fileMedia.Profiles.Select(q => q.ProfileId).Contains(item)
         select fileMedia).
         Concat(query.Where(w => !w.Profiles.Any())).AsQueryable();
```